# Sequelize request not ordering records correctly

Tags: sequelize.js

I am using the following Sequelize request to get a vehicle booking by booking Id. The linked vehicle and its photos are included.

```
Bookings.findAll({
    where: {
        id: bookingid,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.vehicles,
            include: {
                model: db.photos,
                order: [["photoOrder", "ASC"]],
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

It works in that I get the correct data but the photos are not in order of photoOrder ascending.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "bookingCost": 123,
        "userId": 1,
        "vehicleId": 1,
        "vehicle": {
            "id": 1,
            "model": "fiesta",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "photoOrder": 2,
                    "photoUrl": "https://xxx.jpg",
                    "vehicleId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "photoOrder": 1,
                    "photoUrl": "https://yyy.jpg",
                    "vehicleId": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? My associations are:

```
db.vehicles.hasMany(db.bookings);
db.bookings.belongsTo(db.vehicles);

db.vehicles.hasMany(db.photos);
db.photos.belongsTo(db.vehicles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` option is for top level.

You can do

```
Bookings.findAll({
  where: ...,
  include: ...,
  order: [[db.vehicles, db.photos, "photoOrder", "ASC"]]
})
```

===============================

UPDATE:

`order` option can be applied for `include`. However, to take an effect, you'll need to add `separate: true`.

```
Bookings.findAll({
  where: ...,
  include: {
    model: db.vehicles,
    include: {
      model: db.photos,
      separate: true,
      order: [["photoOrder", "ASC"]]
    }
  }
})
```

This `separate: true` will execute 2 queries.

The original answer of putting `order` into top-level will execute 1 query.

If data is small, I think either option works just fine, so it's just a preference.

Comment: I am getting "Unable to find a valid association for model, 'photo'" with this. I have added my associations to the quesiton.

Comment: Can you also add the generated SQL?

Comment: Interesting that you have to have all nesting associations. Updating answer

Comment: Thanks for this. Just getting used to Sequelize. Both your methods and it has been super helpful in understanding what needs to be done. Much appreciated.